# Instantiating objects in python

Tags: python

I have a python class I want to instantiate and the `__init__` definition has a lot of parameters (10+). Is there a clean way to instantiate a class who's `__init__` takes a lot of params?

For example:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3,...param13):
    // create an instance of A


my_a = new A(param1="foo", param2="bar", param3="hello"....)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? like passing in a dictionary or something? Or better, is there an expected convention?

Comment: WHY does the init have so many parameters?

Comment: I REALLY Hope your params are not really named like this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `dict` to collect the parameters:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        print param1, param2, param3


params = {'param1': "foo", 'param2': "bar", 'param3': "hello"}
# no 'new' here, just call the class
my_a = A(**params)
```

See the [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) section of the Python tutorial.

Also, `//` isn't a comment in Python, it's floor division. `#` is a comment. For multi-line comments, `'''You can use triple single quotes'''` or `"""triple double quotes"""`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `new` keyword in Python. You just invoke the class name as you would a function.

You may specify keyword arguments using a dictionary by prefixing the dictionary with `**`, for example:

```
options = {
    "param1": "foo",
    "param2": "bar",
    "param3": "baz"
}

my_a = A(**options)
```

If you're going to be defining all of the values at once, using a dictionary doesn't really give you any advantage over just specifying them directly while using extra whitespace for clairity:

```
my_a = A(
    param1 = "foo",
    param2 = "bar",
    param3 = "baz"
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't call it `args`, the convention in Python is for `args` to be a list of positional parameters, not a `dict`.

Comment: In regards to defining them all at once -- if you're going to use the same parameters in multiple places, you only have to have them in your code once if you use a `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

its not good passing too many arguments to a constructor. but if you want to do this,try:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        """
        provide list of parameters and documentation
        """
        print *args, **kwargs
params = {'param1': "foo", 'param2': "bar", 'param3': "hello"}
a = A(**params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, having that many parameters is often a sign that a class is too complicated and should be split up.

If that doesn't apply, pass up a dictionary, or a special parameter object.